# Calculating the integral $\int \sqrt{1+\sin x}\, dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I want to calculate the integral $\int \sqrt{1+\sin x}\, dx$.

I have done the following:
\begin{equation*}\int \sqrt{1+\sin x}\, dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx\end{equation*}

We substitute $$u=\sqrt{1-\sin x} \Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\cdot (1-\sin x)'\, dx \Rightarrow du=-\frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx \\ \Rightarrow  -2\, du=\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx $$

We get the following: 
\begin{equation*}\int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int(-2)\, du=-2\cdot \int 1\, du=-2u+c\end{equation*}

Therefore \begin{equation*}\int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx=-2\sqrt{1-\sin x}+c\end{equation*}

In Wolfram the answer is a different one. What have I done wrong?

Comment: $$\sqrt{a ^2}=|a|$$  for real $a$  Use $$\left(\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2\right)^2=?$$

Comment: $$\sqrt{\cos^2 x}=|\cos x|$$

Comment: How do we use this relation? I got stuck right now. @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @MaryStar,$$\sqrt{1+\sin x}=\left|\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2\right|$$

Comment: Ah ok! So, we have to calculate $\int \left|\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2\right| dx$. But what do we have to do with the absolute values? @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by other answers, you need to take signs into consideration. Indeed, starting from your computation we know that

$$ \int \sqrt{1+\sin x} \, dx = \int \frac{\left|\cos x\right|}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}} \, dx $$

Now let $I$ be an interval on which $\cos x$ has the constant sign $\epsilon \in \{1, -1\}$. That is, assume that $\left| \cos x \right| = \epsilon \cos x$ for all $x \in I$. Then

\begin{align*}
\text{on } I \ : \qquad
\int \sqrt{1+\sin x} \, dx
&= \epsilon \int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}} \, dx \\
&= -2\epsilon \sqrt{1-\sin x} + C \\
&= - \frac{2\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\sin x}} + C
\end{align*}

In the last line, we utilized the equality $\cos x = \epsilon \left|\cos x\right| = \epsilon \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$.

Notice that maximal choices of $I$ are of the form $I_k := [(k-\frac{1}{2})\pi, (k+\frac{1}{2})\pi]$. So if you want a solution which works on a larger interval, you have to stitch solutions on $I_k$ for different $k$'s together in continuous way. This causes values of $C$ change for different intervals $I_k$. But from the periodicity, it is not terribly hard to describe a global solution and indeed it can be written as

$$
\int \sqrt{1+\sin x} \, dx
= - \frac{2\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\sin x}} + 2\sqrt{2} \left( \left\lceil \frac{x+\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\pi} \right\rceil+ \left\lfloor \frac{x+\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\pi} \right\rfloor \right) + C
$$

The extra term of floor/ceiling function is introduces to compensate jumps of $y=-2\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\sin x}}$:

$\hspace{2em}$ [image: Graph of the antiderivative]

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the given integral using trigonometric/hyperbolic substitutions :

$$\int \sqrt{1+\sin x} dx  ={\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\dfrac{2x-{\pi}}{4}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Apply the substitution :

$$u=\dfrac{2x-{\pi}}{4} \to dx = 2du$$

which means the integral becomes equal to :

$$=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{2^\frac{3}{2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\cos\left(u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u =2^\frac{3}{2}\sin\left(u\right)$$

Undo now the substitution for $u$ and get :

$$=2^\frac{3}{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{2x-{\pi}}{4}\right)$$

which means that :

$$\int \sqrt{1+\sin x} dx =2^\frac{3}{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{2x-{\pi}}{4}\right) + C =2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)-2\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)+C$$

Comment: How do we get that $$ \sqrt{1+\sin x} =\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\dfrac{2x-{\pi}}{4}\right)$$

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin(x)}{2}}\stackrel{x=z+\frac{\pi}{2}}{=}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(z)}{2}}=\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)=\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Comment: But doesn't it hold that $$\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos z}{2}}=\sqrt{\cos^2\frac{z}{2}}=\left |\cos\frac{z}{2}\right |$$ Or do we nor need the absolute value? @DavidP

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\begin{equation*}\int \sqrt{1+\sin x}\, dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx\end{equation*}$$ which is true up to your last equality where you forgot your $\sqrt {cos^2x}=|cos(x)|$ and replaced it with  $\sqrt {cos^2x}=cos(x)$

Comment: So, do I have to add just a $\pm$, i.e.  $$\int \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\int \frac{|\cos x|}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx=\pm \int \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\, dx$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to go.

Comment: So, is the result then $\mp 2\sqrt{1-\sin x}+c$ ?

Comment: Check it by taking derivative.

Comment: Can we just write $\pm$ or do we have to write $\text{sgn}(\cos(x))$ ?

Comment: The second one is prefered.

Comment: Ok! But is this the same as the result of the answer Rebellos?